# printing lines from files

Tags: fstream, getline

I'm trying to print the first line from each file but I think its outputting the address instead.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void FirstLineFromFile(ifstream files[], size_t count)
{
    const int BUFSIZE = 511;        
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    ifstream *end, *start;

    for (start = files, end = files + count; start < end; start++)
    {
        cout << start->getline(buf, sizeof(buf)) << '\n';   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

streams should not be passed by value. This code passes an array of streams by value. You can try to pass a vector instead and interate over them.

```
void FirstLineFromFile(vector<ifstream*> files) {
    for (int i=0; i<files.size(); ++i) {
        string s;
        getline(*files[i], s);
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: for (start = files, end = files + count; start < end; start++)
        {
         getline(*start, s);
         cout << s << '\n';
        }

Answer (score 0):

[ifstream->getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) does not return a string as its return value. You need to print out the buffer that it has filled in a separate line.

```
for (start = files, end = files + count; start < end; start++)
{
    start->getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    cout << buf << '\n';   
}
```